# Impossibility to find the General Term of a sequence (or series)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Is there a way to formally show that the General Term of a sequence cannot be inferred from some set of given information? If so, how can one do that?

An example to illustrate what I mean is:

> Find the General Term of the series 
>   $$\frac{1}{2} + \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{4} + \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{9} + \left(\frac{4}{16}\right)^{16} + \cdots$$

I'm actually asking this question, because my real analysis exam was typed wrong and the fourth term was printed $(4/16)^{16}$ instead of $(4/5)^{16}$, which would make it possible to show that the General Term is :

$$a_n=\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n^2}.$$

I was warned to change it, but then this question came to my mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When we write "$\ldots$" in mathematics, we are really saying "and continue on in the obvious way".  But, as you point out, "the obvious way" is open to interpretation.

The answer to your question is 'no': for one way to see why, consider [*polynomial interpolation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation). Given any $n$ values $x_1,\ldots,x_n$, you can find an (at most) $n$th degree polynomial $p$ so that $p(i)=x_i$ for all $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.  So, if you are given a sequence of some number of terms, you can always choose ANY further set of finite terms you want, use them to come up with a polynomial, use that polynomial as a rule for a sequence, and feel completely justified that your answer is "reasonable".

That's why we have to be so careful with our "and so on", "obvious", "clear", "$\ldots$", etc.

Comment: So there actually is a way to create a rule for any finite set of terms, which answers my question with a "no", right? How is that method called? I would like to read more about it.

Comment: That's right, the answer is no.

Finding a polynomial to match a data set is called *polynomial interpolation*; you can read more about it at, for instance, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation).

And if you liked my answer, please consider accepting it.  Welcome to math.stackexchange!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that all you need to do is find a cubic (or any four-parameter sequence) whose first four terms are $2, 3, 4, 16$.